# C# Force subclasses to implement a static method

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, static-methods

I am currently building a class library to handle unit measurements and I wanted to use the factory pattern with static methods to create lengths or areas and so on.

To keep the methods consistent I wanted to create an interface or a superclass. Is there a possible way to enforce subclasses to implement a static method?

(Offtopic: Is it also possible to enforce subclasses to overload operators?)

**For example:**

```
public class Length
    {...


    public static Length Create(double value, string unitCode)
        {
            var length = new Length();

            switch (unitCode)
            {
                case "Mm":
                    length.Megameters = value;
                    break;
                case "Km":
                case "km":
                    length.Kilometers = value;
                    break;
                case "hm":
                    length.Hectometers = value;
                    break;
                case "dam":
                    length.Decameters = value;
                    break;
                case "m":
                    length.Meters = value;
                    break;
                case "dm":
                    length.Decimeters = value;
                    break;
                case "cm":
                    length.Centimeters = value;
                    break;
                case "mm":
                    length.Millimeters = value;
                    break;
                case "µm":
                    length.Micrometers = value;
                    break;
                case "pm":
                    length.Picometers = value;
                    break;
                case "in":
                    length.Inches = value;
                    break;
                case "ft":
                    length.Feet = value;
                    break;
                case "yd":
                    length.Yards = value;
                    break;
                case "mi":
                    length.Miles = value;
                    break;
                case "smi":
                    length.ScandinavianMiles = value;
                    break;
                case "ly":
                    length.LightYears = value;
                    break;
                case "NM":
                    length.NauticalMiles = value;
                    break;
                case "ftm":
                    length.Fathoms = value;
                    break;
                case "fur":
                    length.Furlongs = value;
                    break;
                case "ua":
                    length.AstronomicalUnits = value;
                    break;
                case "pc":
                    length.Parsecs = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid unit given.", nameof(unitCode));
            }
            return length;
        }
... }
```

Comment: It's impossible to do that. The nearest thing you can do is an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) or enforce it through Reflection.

Comment: Interfaces can only force instance members, but since static members can't be overriden anyway, if you have a single base class for all your subclasses they will all share whatever static members the base class have.

Comment: Why would subclass at all needs to implement that since that method is anyways available to subclass

Comment: BTW, why don't you keep a single property for length and a single property for units? That would make your code much simpler. I would also implement a length converter that would take the length and the source unit and translate it to the target unit - if that's something you do in your application.

Comment: @Luke, I think extension methods wouldn't help in this case. I just want keep the code constistent for all classes which have sth. to do with unit of measurement.

These properties are pointing to the same private attribute, they just use different coefficients to write or read the attribute.

Comment: @Rathul, I just want to have the method names consistent and use the same methods for all unit types like length, area, volume, weight, etc.

Comment: @LukeVo, I think extension methods wouldn't help in this case. Well, I really never worked with extension methods, but I understand it as extending class functionality extern classes. For instance, if you need a method for strings, but it wasn't implemented in the beginning. Correct me if I am wrong. What are the benefits of extension methods and when should I use it in a normal case?